# Show empty rows in a select SQLite query using pd.read_sql

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite

I want to create a pandas dataframe using a list of codes to search information in a SQLite table related to those codes. I know how to make the SQLite query giving a list of codes. The thing I want to add and I don't know how to do it is to add an empty row for those codes that we don't have information with the code and all the rest of the data empty, instead of ignoring that code as SQLite does. Here is an schematic example:

```
Code     atributes
a        data
b        data
empty    -
c        data
c        data
```

where empty means a code that does not appear in the database.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want 1 extra row with Code = 'empty' and attributes = '-'? If so, why in that position?

Comment: I make a query with a list of codes. For the codes that are in the database, it finds information in the DB and insert the rows with that code information. 
For the codes that are not in the database, I want to add a row with the code an a "-" in the data columns to indicate that that code is not in the database. I don't know if I explain myself clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply left join merge on a data frame of all codes where any mismatches will render `NaN` in all columns:

```
df_codes = pd.DataFrame({'Code': mylistofcodes})

df_sql = df_codes.merge(df_sql, on='Code', how='left')
```

Alternatively, you can run a `LEFT JOIN` merge in SQL using a one-column temp table of all codes where `NULL` renders in mismatched columns. You can then run below query with `pd.read_sql`:

```sql
SELECT c.Code, t.attributes
FROM myCodes c
LEFT JOIN myTable t
  ON t.Code = c.Code
```